# How to Make height:"100%" work HTML5

Tags: html, css, dynamic

I am trying to embed this in my site and make my site resize to fit the content so the container with the embedded content has no scroll bar, only the main page (hope this makes sense). Below is what I am doing now, however height 100% won't work

```
<embed src="https://shop.inventarnd.com/index.php?rt=product/product&product_id=124" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
```

The width is working but height does not work.

**I have already tried the following**

- Making parent tags such as html, body, etc... have height 100%
  Here is a link to my site where i want to embed it.

https://www.inventarnd.com/test.html

I want to have ***[this](https://shop.inventarnd.com/index.php?rt=product/product&product_id=124)*** web page embedded on my site and have the scroll bar not be there. So have the web page automatically resize to fit the embedded content.

Comment: Do you have control of the content of the page you are embedding? If not, you probably can't do that.

Comment: If you do, you can use JavaScript to send a message from the embedded page to the container page to tell it how tall the embedded page's content is, and set the height of the embed element to that height.

Comment: I own the website and have full access to all resources of both websites. How would I use JS to do what you said @Alohci? Please add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an iframe, this might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

The background is clear, so the previous page will show through but the scrollbar and content are all ok. I would change the background to white as well, but I'm not sure what you are and aren't able to do.

Comment: I have full access to the code, I can change anything. I want the embedded content to be in the place where it is now, but dynamically resize based upon the content. If I make it absolute it is hard to position.